# Add A Tag To A Post Through JavaScript In Gutenberg UI?

Tags: javascript, tags, block-editor, admin-ui

My creators have a large variety of tags (500+), and want a "tag grouping" button to click and add sets of related tags through the Gutenberg UI.  I could easily add them through PHP hooks, yadda yadda, but they really wanna see the tags added live in the post editor so they can potentially delete a tag, etc etc.

...how would that be done in the new framework?